# uthash C HASH_FIND

Tags: c, hashtable, uthash

I've got a homework from university and are supposed to use the library uthash to implement a hashtable including a set-, get- and delete-function. Hashtable is our struct containing a key, its length, a value, its length too and a `UT_hash_handle` (which seems to be necessary).

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct hashtable {
    unsigned char *key;
    size_t k_len; 
    unsigned char *value; 
    size_t v_len;
    UT_hash_handle hashhandle;
} hashtable;
```

And our predefined function-head is the following:

```
hashtable get_value(hashtable **ht, const unsigned char *key, size_t key_len);
```

Regarding to our task I should use the `HASH_FIND`-function from uthash to get a hashvalue by key. I thought this would be easy (and probably it is) but sadly I don't understand the usage of the `HASH_FIND`-function in detail and the official documentation isn't very helpful because it just shows the usage of `HASH_FIND_INT`.

So, `HASH_FIND` wants me to give it five parameters:

```
HASH_FIND(hh, head, keyptr, keylen, out)
```

The values, which I should use for `keyptr` and `keylen`, are no problem (I'll just give it the parameter `key` and `key_len` which I receive as a parameter in my function). For the value out, I think I should create a new `struct` from our hashtable-struct and give it to `HASH_FIND`. For the head-parameter, I think it's just necessary to give the pointer to my hashtable (which I get as a parameter to my function by our specification).
But what exactly does the hash_handle means? Should I get the hash_handle-value out of our predefined struct and then give it to `HASH_FIND`?

Thank you for helping me out!

I want to look up a value out of the hashtable using `HASH_FIND` from uthash.

Comment: So `hashtable` is the entry in your hash table? Is this some sort of inception?

Answer (score 1):

`hh` is meant to be the name of the `UT_hash_handle` member of your value struct (which in the convenience macros like `HASH_FIND_INT` is hardcoded to be `hh`), so would just be `hashhandle` here.

The `out` parameter should be a `hashtable *`, which will either be set to point to the found element, or to `NULL` if not found.